# What is the best way to listen for new files in a directory?

Tags: directory, listen

I am looking for some guidance on the best way for my program to be alerted that there is a new file in a directory that needs to be picked up and read. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What programming language are you using?  Java?

Comment: @StephenC yes java. I need to pick up PDF files, convert to text and dump them in an outbound directory. Just not sure what the best approach is for listening for new files in the inbound directory

Answer (score 1):

This would probably depend on your use case. If you need to listen for new files and then run a script: on Unix you could write a cronjob that checks every few min or so for new files in the directory (or via job scheduler for windows). And if the cronjob sees a new file it could start a script

But it sounds like you have an on going program that files will be added while the script is running?
In that case you could use whatever multithreading library exists for the language the program is written in. You could have one thread constantly monitoring the directory and able to add them to a queue or other data structure or spawn new threads

Comment: Thanks my use case isn't very unique. I need to listen to a directory for new files which will be in PDF format. When they arrive I will have to read them into java and convert them to Text files(I'm using the PDFbox jar  from apache for that part) then I need to dump them into an out directory.